# summarise dataframe in respect to two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row

```
df <- data.frame(sd = c('05AP.U1 1','05AP.U1 1','05AP.U1 1','05AP.U1 1','05AP.U1 1','05AP.U1 1','05AP.U2 1','05AP.U2 1','05AP.U2 1','05AP.U2 1','05AP.U2 1','07RT.U1 1','07RT.U1 1','07RT.U1 1','07RT.U1 1'),soure = c('plant','plant','plant','plant','plant','animal','animal','animal','animal','animal','plant','plant','plant','animal','animal'),en = c(184.45,15.78,00.00,1541.15,12.15,456.14,78.45,94.84,4661.1,165,156,28,165.12,158,132.2),percentpl = c(50,50,50,50,50,0,0,0,0,0,40,80,80,0,0),percentan = c(0,0,0,0,0,50,60,60,60,60,0,0,0,20,20))
> df

> df
          sd  soure      en  percentpl  percentan
1  05AP.U1 1  plant  184.45  50        0
2  05AP.U1 1  plant   15.78  50        0
3  05AP.U1 1  plant    0.00  50        0
4  05AP.U1 1  plant 1541.15  50        0
5  05AP.U1 1  plant   12.15  50        0
6  05AP.U1 1 animal  456.14  0         50
7  05AP.U2 1 animal   78.45   0        60
8  05AP.U2 1 animal   94.84   0        60
9  05AP.U2 1 animal 4661.10   0        60
10 05AP.U2 1 animal  165.00   0        60
11 05AP.U2 1  plant  156.00   40       0
12 07RT.U1 1  plant   28.00   80       0
13 07RT.U1 1  plant  165.12   80       0
14 07RT.U1 1 animal  158.00    0       20
15 07RT.U1 1 animal  132.20    0       20
```

Now I want `df` to looklike this

```
    sd        percentpl  percentan
1  05AP.U1 1      50        50
9  05AP.U2 1      40        60
12 07RT.U1 1      80        20
```

So I want to summarise `df` in respect to the percentages and sd's (summarise probably is not the right word). The new df can be called differently, in case that is easier. I actually have no idea how to do this...

EDIT:
`sd` are food samples. `percentpl` and `percentan` are percentages of two variables I cut short here. In the end I want to have a plot with the percentages as x and y axis and the dots of the plot should be the samples `sd`.

Comment: Please explain the logic of *why* you have selected the values that you have selected for each `sd`.

Comment: Please add reproducible `dput(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(sd) %>%
    summarise(percentpl = unique(percentpl[percentpl!=0]), 
              percentan = unique(percentan[percentan!=0]))
```

Or also

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(sd) %>%
    summarise(across(c(percentpl, percentan),
                     ~unique(.[.!=0])))
```